# Создание нового контакта в группе

Tags: android

```
if (contacts != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> op = new ArrayList<>();
        /* Добавляем пустой контакт */
        op.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                .build());
        /* Добавляем данные имени */
        op.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, contacts.get(i).author)
                .build());
        /* Добавляем данные телефона */
        op.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, "+" + contacts.get(i).phone_number)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                .build());
        op.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newAssertQuery(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE + "=?", new String[] {"Мастера"})
                .withExpectedCount(1)
                .build());
        try {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, op);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("333: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Предполагалось что будут созданы новые контакты в группе "Мастера", но что то пошло не так... Контакты создаются, но в основном списке. Где недоглядел?